# pentaho HTTP Status 404 -

Tags: apache, pentaho

Good Morning for some good evening for others. First of all I install pentaho on linux first time everything works fine I follow this instruccions for installing and start the BA server
[Pentaho Info center](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/config_ba_server/task_starting_ba_server.html)
the first time I log in everything works fine. But when I try to continue my learning curve today I run this commands for startup the services on terminal: `/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/start-pentaho.sh` follow by  `./ctlscript.sh start baserver.`

this is the output of the first command

> /opt/pentaho 
>   /opt/pentaho
>   DEBUG: Found JAVA two folders up
>   DEBUG: Found Pentaho License two folders up
>   DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=/opt/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/../../java
>   DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=/opt/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/../../java/bin/java
>   DEBUG: PENTAHO_INSTALLED_LICENSE_PATH=/opt/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/../../.installedLicenses.xml 
>   Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat
>   Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat
>   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat/temp
>   Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/../../java
>   Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar
>   Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat
>   Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat
>   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat/temp
>   Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
>   Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar

And this is the output of the second command

> Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat 
>   Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat
>   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat/temp
>   Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/pentaho/java
>   Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar
>   /opt/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat/scripts/ctl.sh : BA Server started

When I'll try to access to my > `http://localhost:8080/pentaho/` I got the error HTTP Status 404. i try to run this command to `service apache2 start` . I run this command to `./ctlscript.sh status baserver` to see if i get some information but nothing happen no output.So when I try again same error happens, I don't know what is the problem the platform works well before(yesterday). thank you for any help or comments.

Comment: I have new content when I run the `./ctlscript.sh status postgresql` the output is **postgresql not running**. So when I try to start postgreql whit this command `/ctlscript.sh start postgresql ` the output is an error: **waiting for server to start........ stopped waiting
pg_ctl.bin: could not start server
Examine the log output.
/opt/pentaho/postgresql/scripts/ctl.sh : postgresql  could not be started**

Comment: I fix the problem you have to manually start: baserver, postgressql and data-integration-server

Answer (score 0):

check if the server is running with the help of

ps -ef|grep postgres
ps -ef|grep Pentaho

kill the processes .
Restart the server one by one
 ./ctlscript.sh start postgresql
 ./ctlscript.sh start baserver

Then open catalina.out file and see if server is started properly.
tail -f server/biserver-ee/tomcat/logs/catalina.out

Ping me the logs if you have still issues.